# How to loop the Animation and between with 10 seconds

Tags: cocoa, animation

LogoAnimation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:How can I implement a 10 Seconds Pause"Break" between the Loop Animation? Like the first Animation runs then 10 Pause and after 10 Seconds the same Animation again and again and again. I tried everything but I don't know exactly how to fix it! 
Here my Code:

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    LogoAnimation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_01"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_02"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_03"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_04"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_05"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_06"], nil];


    [LogoAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    LogoAnimation.animationDuration = 2;

    [LogoAnimation startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:LogoAnimation];


}
```

Comment: What class is `LogoAnimation`? What is `TestAnimation`? If you'd like anybody to spent time answering your question how about providing some background?

Comment: Sorry, now i made the correction. It's LogoAnimation and not TestAnimation!!!! Look again mate :-)! And what do you mean "providing some background"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I assume that you are using a UIImageView and that LogoAnimation and TestAnimation should actually be the same thing?

UIImageView does not give you this functionality. To do this with a UIImageView you could either add more images to the end of your array to correspond to 10seconds of the same image. Or you could have a 1 repeat count on the UIImageView and have an NSTimer fire every 10 seconds to start the animation.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    TestAnimation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_01"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_02"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_03"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_04"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_05"],
                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"TestAnimation_06"], nil];


    [TestAnimation setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    TestAnimation.animationDuration = 2;
    [TestAnimation startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:TestAnimation];

    // You need to add a property to your interface @property (strong) NSTimer *timer;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:12.0 target:TestAnimation selector:@selector(startAnimating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; // 12.0 interval = 2s animation + 10s wait between.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self.timer invalidate];
}
```

Comment: Where should i put the NSTimer?

Comment: After the [LogoAnimation startAnimating]; 
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:12.0 target:TestAnimation selector:@selector(startAnimating) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; ???

Comment: Yes, at the end of the view did load method, I have updated the answer.

Comment: There is a yellow triangle on the left site and it's written Unused variable 'timer' :/

Comment: See my update for that line, also check the comment on the line above :)

Comment: thank you mate. Now there is a red call sign in the left site and it's written "Property 'timer' not found on object of type "ViewController" ^^. What did i do wrong ?

Comment: I think now it works ^^it was the @property (strong) NSTimer *timer;

Comment: I'm new here and i dont know how this works here ? should I vote you ? or give you 5 stars or something for your help :D ?

Comment: If this has solved your problem you should click the tick next to the answer to accept it as the answer. Glad I could help!

Comment: Okay mate! I have another question. I would like to put another NSArray arrayWithObjects: Animation. but the problem is that it doesn't let me write a second NSArray arrayWithObjects. Right now the TestAnimation.animationImages= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: does exist. I want to put a second animation. How should I do that ? can you solve this maybe ?

Comment: And it doesn't let me do a second - (void)viewDidLoad

Comment: It doesn't let me write a second NSArray arrayWithObjects. I want to do a second one in the - (void)viewDidLoad like TestAnimation2. animationImage= [NSArray arrayWithObjects: but it doesn't work :S

Comment: Can you add the code from both the .h and .m files to the question..?

Comment: Are you using interface builder?

Comment: I add the 2 Files. Look at my ViewController.m and ViewController.h. Thank you soo much!!^^

Comment: Yes I'm using the Interface builder. Until now, everything works fine. The only thing what not isn't working, is the other Animation in the - "(void)viewDidLoad" what I attached. :/